# HashSet vs LinkedHashSet and different results for the same task

Tags: dart

Please, Can you explain, these different results. [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ece4dbf82260de0a2315654dbc2af187)

Yet, Java has different point of view  [online runner](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUGpLQVQ0MUZ5VVU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of `HashSet` and `List`, it looks like `removeWhere` is collecting the elements to be removed and then removing them all at the end. For `LinkedHashSet`, it is removing them as soon as they are found. `removeWhere` does not document it's implementation details, so I think it's unwise to give a `test` to `removeWhere` that depends on the contents of the `List` or `Set`.

Comment: It’s beyond me. To be honest I suppose the same result )) Your answer follows the logic. Thanks.